# Visual Studio Code go to next error or warning, but not to info

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code and I know that I can go to the next error with <kbd>F8</kbd>. I am also using a spell checker plugin, which shows me `info` messages. When I press <kbd>F8</kbd> I also go to the next `info` message.

Not so strange, because F8 is mapped to "Go to Next Problem in Files (Error, Warning, Info). Is it possible to configure the keybinding with a filter and only go to the next error or warning?

[image: F8 keymap settings]

Comment: It doesn't look like this is currently possible. I filed an issue for this here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/105795

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [add options for jumping to next/previous problem](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/135736)
.  This seems to do what you want - you can test it in the Insiders' Build now.

This setting is being added (due in v1.63):

`Problems: Compare Order`

Options: `Severity` and `Position`

---

From [release notes: define problem order navigation](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_63.md#define-order-problem-navigation)

> #### Define order problem navigation
>
> You can now define the order in which "Go to Next Problem"
> (kb(`editor.action.marker.next`)) and "Go to Previous Problem"
> (kb(`editor.action.marker.prev`)) work. In previous versions
> navigation would happen by severity, first come errors, then warnings,
> then the rest. The new `problems.sortOrder` - configuration enables
> you to navigate problems by their position instead. So, a warning line
> 5 will be shown before an error on line 13 etc.

In my testing `severity` navigates to errors, and not infos when you press <kbd>F8</kbd> (and may be the new default).  `position` visits all problem types (errors, warnings and infos) in the line number order.